# Extracting data from a .txt file without using modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I am taking a course in python and one of the problem sets is as follows:

> Read in the contents of the file SP500.txt which has monthly data for 2016 and 2017 about the S&P 500 closing prices as well as some other financial indicators, including the “Long Term Interest Rate”, which is interest rate paid on 10-year U.S. government bonds.

> Write a program that computes the average closing price (the second column, labeled SP500) and the highest long-term interest rate. Both should be computed only for the period from June 2016 through May 2017. Save the results in the variables mean_SP and max_interest.

SP500.txt:

> Date,SP500,Dividend,Earnings,Consumer Price Index,Long Interest Rate,Real Price,Real Dividend,Real Earnings,PE10
> 1/1/2016,1918.6,43.55,86.5,236.92,2.09,2023.23,45.93,91.22,24.21
> 2/1/2016,1904.42,43.72,86.47,237.11,1.78,2006.62,46.06,91.11,24
> 3/1/2016,2021.95,43.88,86.44,238.13,1.89,2121.32,46.04,90.69,25.37
> 4/1/2016,2075.54,44.07,86.6,239.26,1.81,2167.27,46.02,90.43,25.92
> 5/1/2016,2065.55,44.27,86.76,240.23,1.81,2148.15,46.04,90.23,25.69
> 6/1/2016,2083.89,44.46,86.92,241.02,1.64,2160.13,46.09,90.1,25.84
> 7/1/2016,2148.9,44.65,87.64,240.63,1.5,2231.13,46.36,91,26.69
> 8/1/2016,2170.95,44.84,88.37,240.85,1.56,2251.95,46.51,91.66,26.95
> 9/1/2016,2157.69,45.03,89.09,241.43,1.63,2232.83,46.6,92.19,26.73
> 10/1/2016,2143.02,45.25,90.91,241.73,1.76,2214.89,46.77,93.96,26.53
> 11/1/2016,2164.99,45.48,92.73,241.35,2.14,2241.08,47.07,95.99,26.85
> 12/1/2016,2246.63,45.7,94.55,241.43,2.49,2324.83,47.29,97.84,27.87
> 1/1/2017,2275.12,45.93,96.46,242.84,2.43,2340.67,47.25,99.24,28.06
> 2/1/2017,2329.91,46.15,98.38,243.6,2.42,2389.52,47.33,100.89,28.66
> 3/1/2017,2366.82,46.38,100.29,243.8,2.48,2425.4,47.53,102.77,29.09
> 4/1/2017,2359.31,46.66,101.53,244.52,2.3,2410.56,47.67,103.74,28.9
> 5/1/2017,2395.35,46.94,102.78,244.73,2.3,2445.29,47.92,104.92,29.31
> 6/1/2017,2433.99,47.22,104.02,244.96,2.19,2482.48,48.16,106.09,29.75
> 7/1/2017,2454.1,47.54,105.04,244.79,2.32,2504.72,48.52,107.21,30
> 8/1/2017,2456.22,47.85,106.06,245.52,2.21,2499.4,48.69,107.92,29.91
> 9/1/2017,2492.84,48.17,107.08,246.82,2.2,2523.31,48.76,108.39,30.17
> 10/1/2017,2557,48.42,108.01,246.66,2.36,2589.89,49.05,109.4,30.92
> 11/1/2017,2593.61,48.68,108.95,246.67,2.35,2626.9,49.3,110.35,31.3
> 12/1/2017,2664.34,48.93,109.88,246.52,2.4,2700.13,49.59,111.36,32.09

My solution (correct but not optimal):

```py
file = open("SP500.txt", "r")

content = file.readlines()

# List that will hold the range of months we need
data=[]

for line in content:
    # Get a list of values for each line
    values = line.split(',')
    # Return lines with the required dates
    for i in range(6,13):
        month_range = f"{i}/1/2016"
        if month_range == values[0]:
            data.append(values)
    # Return lines with the required dates
    for i in range(1,6):
        month_range = f"{i}/1/2017"
        if month_range == values[0]:
            data.append(values)

sum_total = 0
max_interest = 0
# Loop through the data of our required months
for entry in data:
    # Get the sum total
    sum_price += float(entry[1])
    # Find the highest interest rate in list
    if max_interest < float(entry[5]):
        max_interest = float(entry[5])

mean_SP = sum_total / len(data)
```

I'm self-learning these concepts and I would love to learn a better way of implementing this solution. My code seems borderline hard coding (exact date in values[0]) and I imagine it to be error prone for bigger problems. Especially the excessive looping that's being done, which seems quite exaustive for such a simple problem.
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
New code (based Deepak Tripathi answer):

```py
with open('SP500.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
lines = [line.rstrip().split(",") for line in lines]
date_index, spf_index, long_interest_rate = 0, 1, 5
start_year, end_year = 2016, 2017
start_month, end_month = 6, 5
mean_SP, max_interest = 0, -1000 # Some random negative number
total_entries = 0
for line in lines[1:]:
    date_values = line[date_index].split('/')
    if (int(date_values[2]) == start_year and int(date_values[0]) >= start_month) or (int(date_values[2]) == end_year and int(date_values[0]) <= end_month):
        total_entries += 1
        mean_SP += float(line[spf_index])
        max_interest = max(max_interest, float(line[long_interest_rate]))
mean_SP /= total_entries
print(mean_SP, max_interest)
```

Comment: `SP500.txt` clearly has `.csv` structure, you can use pythons `csv` module instead of pure parsing. You can also parse your date with  `datetime.strptime('8/1/2017', '%d/%m/%Y').date()` instead of manual parsing

Comment: @sudden_appearance Hello sudden, thanks for getting back to me. We're not supposed to use modules for this question but I'd like to use it for practice still. I added it to the code and its receiving the correct date values, and I'm wondering if there is a range attribute I can use with this module?

Comment: Your title needs to summarize your question. _"Elementary Q in python (extracting data from a .txt file without using modules)"_ doesn't describe your question at all (your question is essentially "how do I optimize this code by removing loops").

Comment: @PranavHosangadi It's descriptive enough I believe and this is not a malicious intent on my part to ask for help in writing better code. This is purely for learning as its part of an online course I'm taking which is not going to be submitted. But thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I've removed the "elementary Q..." fluff from the start of your title. I still believe your question should be titled something that indicates that your problem lies in the _optimization_ rather than in the _extraction of data_, but I will let you be the judge of that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can optimized by storing the index of columns in some variable

```
with open('temp.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
lines = [line.rstrip().split(",") for line in lines]
date_index, spf_index, long_interest_rate = 0, 1, 5
start_date, end_date = "01/06/2016", "31/05/2017"
mean_SP, max_interest = 0, -1000 # Some random negative number

for line in lines[1:]:
    if start_date.zfill(10) <= line[date_index] <= end_date.zfill(10):
        mean_SP += float(line[spf_index])
        max_interest = max(max_interest, float(line[long_interest_rate]))
mean_SP /= len(lines[1:])
print(mean_SP, max_interest)
```

Comment: Thank you Deepak, this is exactly what I was looking for. I noticed two parts of the code that are causing issues with this question and I wanted to get your feedback on them. I think the second one can be easily solved if we add an accumulator in our 'if' block because the len function is currently counting all the entries in the list. But it seems like python detects a specific date structure, because when I change the date values to how they're written in the text file(month/day/year), the if check fails.

Comment: For datetime comparison you can check with string as well but for safer side you can convert your string into datetime and then check datetime objects.
And first suggestion is correct you can add accumulator in for loop that will be more fast, for convert datetime suggestion given by @sudden_appearance is quite good.

Comment: Yeah, the datetime module is working great. As for the string comparison however, it's not recognizing the double digit numbers as it should. If it sees '1/' and compares it to '06/', it only checks for each position and returns that month still. I added the working code above based on your code.

Comment: @AliAlsawad I have edited my answer now if the date is 1/06/2014 then it will be changed to 01/06/2014 then comparison will start.

Answer (score -1):

Just find out another answer from:https://gist.github.com/guestPK1986/dfadc3ffe900dae77e86bae4a5af80bd

```
with open("SP500.txt", "r") as file:
    new = file.readlines()
    closing_price = []
    interest_rate = []
    for x in new[6:18]:
        y = x.split(",")
        closing_price.append(y[1])
        interest_rate.append(y[5])
   
    sum_of_numbers = 0
    for each in closing_price:
        sum_of_numbers = sum_of_numbers + float(each)
   
    mean_SP = sum_of_numbers/len(closing_price)
    print(float(mean_SP))
    max_interest = 0
    for i in interest_rate:
        if float(i) > max_interest:
            max_interest = float(i)
    print(max_interest)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

**1.** **max_interest** should be assigned **None** value.

I would *not use a random initial value for max_interest*.

```py
mean_SP, max_interest = 0, -1000  Some random negative number
```

I think it is better to
assign None value to max_interest. In that way, you **avoid the possibility of setting
the initial value to be bigger than anything in the given data**. With max_interest initially containing a bigger value than anything in the given data,
you would get the wrong answer but without an error message - the semantic
error which is the hardest type of error to spot. That's why I prefer the following code
snippet:

```py
max_interest = None  # to initialize the variable
```

To find the max_interest I wrote the following code where the variable long_term is the value of the sixth column, labeled
Long Term Interest Rate (*there is the whole code at the end of the post*):

```py
if max_interest is None or max_interest < long_term:
    max_interest = long_term
```

When you assign None as an initial value to max_interest then you can use the
first encountered value from the actual data as the initial value for
comparison. *max_interest with the value of None* **serves as a placeholder until
the first value from the actual data is assigned to max_interest**.

**2.** **The conditional part of an if-statement is too long.**

You should **assign value of data_values[2] to the variable** for two reasons:

a. It will be *more clear what data we are dealing with*.

b. The conditional part of an *if-statement will be shorter*, therefore, *easier to read*.

Here, I would suggest you read **PEP8** (https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/). Also, I would suggest using **the linters** like **flake8, pylint**, and others.
Here is a part of PEP8.

The Python standard library is conservative and requires **limiting lines to
79 characters (and docstrings/comments to 72).**

The preferred way of wrapping long lines is by using Python s implied line
continuation inside parentheses, brackets, and braces. *Long lines* can be
broken over multiple lines by **wrapping expressions in parentheses**. These
should be used in preference to using a backslash for line continuation.

```
                                ***
```

**When the conditional part of an if-statement is long enough** to require that
it be written across multiple lines, it s worth noting that the combination
of a two character keyword (i.e. if), plus a single space, plus an opening
parenthesis creates a natural 4-space indent for the subsequent lines of the
multiline conditional. This can produce a visual conflict with the indented
suite of code nested inside the if-statement, which would also naturally be
indented to 4 spaces. This PEP takes no explicit position on how (or whether)
to further visually distinguish such conditional lines from the nested suite
inside the if-statement. **Acceptable options** in this situation include, **but
are not limited to**:

```py
     # No extra indentation.
     if (this_is_one_thing and
         that_is_another_thing):
         do_something()

     # Add a comment, which will provide some distinction in editors
     # supporting syntax highlighting.
     if (this_is_one_thing and
         that_is_another_thing):
          Since both conditions are true, we can frobnicate.
         do_something()

     # Add some extra indentation on the conditional continuation line.
     if (this_is_one_thing
             and that_is_another_thing):
         do_something()
```

**3.** *In this course* is **not allowed to use CSV.** Although, it is very logical to use CSV module.

For **selecting period between June 2016 through May 2017**, I would suggest the following:

a. *converting every string/line of the file (except the first one which is header) into a list of
strings* where *the first item in the list is date*.

b. *Date itself is string* and should be *converted to a list of strings, again*. Here, *the first item* is *a month* and *the last item* is *a year*.

c. Then
*convert* those strings of month and year *into integers*.

```py
   # Period June 2016 through May 2017
        columns = line.strip().split(',')
        date = columns[0].split('/')
        month = int(date[0])
        year = int(date[2])
```

**4.** Here is my **whole code**.

```py
"""

Read in the contents of the file SP500.txt which has monthly date for 2016 and
2017 about the S&P 500 closing prices as well as some other financial
indicators, including the  Long Term Interest Rate , which is interest rate
paid on 10-year U.S. government bonds.

Write a program that computes the average closing price (the second column,
labeled SP500) and the highest long-term interest rate. Both should be computed
only for the period from June 2016 through May 2017. Save the results in the
variables mean_SP and max_interest.

"""

count_header = 0

total_closing_price = 0
count_closing_price = 0

max_interest = None

with open('SP500.txt', 'r') as fileref:
    for line in fileref:

        # skip the header
        count_header += 1
        if count_header == 1:
            continue

        # Period June 2016 through May 2017
        columns = line.strip().split(',')
        date = columns[0].split('/')
        month = int(date[0])
        year = int(date[2])

        if ((year == 2016 and 6 <= month <= 12)
                or (year == 2017 and 1 <= month <= 5)):

            # The average closing price (the second column, labeled SP500)
            sp500 = float(columns[1])
            total_closing_price += sp500
            count_closing_price += 1

            # The highest long-term interest rate, (the sixth column, labeled
            # Long Term Interest Rate)
            long_term = float(columns[5])
            if max_interest is None or max_interest < long_term:
                max_interest = long_term


mean_SP = total_closing_price / count_closing_price

print(mean_SP)
print(max_interest)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).